# How to get the selected count, in the template, of selected items from select element in angular?

Tags: angular, nebular

I have the following markup in my template:

```
<label for="restCuisine" class="label">Cuisine</label><br/>
{{ getCount(selected) }} selected
<nb-select 
    multiple 
    [(selected)]="selected"
    formControlName="restCuisine" 
    id="restCuisine">
    <nb-option value="International">International</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Chinese">Chinese</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Greek">Greek</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Middle Eastern">Middle Eastern</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Caribbean">Caribbean</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Asian">Asian</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Local">Local</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Japanese">Japanese</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Mexican">Mexican</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Indian">Indian</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="British">British</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="European">European</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Italian">Italian</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="French">French</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Spanish">Spanish</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Cajun">Cajun</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Thai">Thai</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Mediterranean">Mediterranean</nb-option>
</nb-select>
```

I'm trying to the get the selected items count like so:

```
selected;    

getCount(selected: any) {
    return selected.length();
}
```

but it doesn't work. I tried different examples from the web but it's not what I'm looking for. I was thinking of referencing the element using ViewChild and overriding the change event of the element then counting the items in selected but that's too much code. I'm looking for a one or two liner.

How do I get the number of selected items of the select element? The real challenge is to do this only in the template but typescript will be fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple with selectedChange and interpolation. Find below the answer:

```
<label for="restCuisine" class="label">Cuisine</label><br/>
<p>{{ restCuisineCount }} selected</p>
<nb-select 
    multiple 
    fullWidth
    (selectedChange)="onChangeRestCuisine($event)"
    formControlName="restCuisine" 
    id="restCuisine">
    <nb-option value="International">International</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Chinese">Chinese</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Greek">Greek</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Middle Eastern">Middle Eastern</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Caribbean">Caribbean</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Asian">Asian</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Local">Local</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Japanese">Japanese</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Mexican">Mexican</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Indian">Indian</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="British">British</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="European">European</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Italian">Italian</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="French">French</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Spanish">Spanish</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Cajun">Cajun</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Thai">Thai</nb-option>
    <nb-option value="Mediterranean">Mediterranean</nb-option>
</nb-select>
```

and typescript:

```
restCuisineCount = 0;

onChangeRestCuisine(event: any) {
    this.restCuisineCount = event.length;
}
```